# Facebook og meta tags - scraper fetches nothing

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, meta-tags

So I have this [cakephp project](https://philippidescompetition.com/landing), when I share the link to facebook i don't get og:description, og:image etc, even though everything seems to be there.

**My code:** (Views/Layouts/default.ctp)

```
<head>
...
<meta property="og:url" content="<?=Configure::read('og_url');?>landing" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=Configure::read('app_title');?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=Configure::read('og_description');?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=Configure::read('og_image');?>" />
...
</head>
```

*I initialize everything in bootsrap.php so all my files can have access to these values.*

Which produces this, **View Page Source:**

```
<head>
...
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.philippidescompetition.com/landing" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Back To School Spin & Win! " />
<meta property="og:description" content="Συμπλήρωσε τα στοιχεία σου και παίξε "Spin & Win"!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.philippidescompetition.com/img/wheel/og_image_s.jpg" />
...
</head>
```

So far so good, but when I share the link on facebook **I don't get any of the meta data.**
I tried the debugger tool, but it didn't really help.

I want to share `philippidescompetition.com/landing` this link, which redirects to the `facebook app page` or to the actual url `philippidescompetition.com/users/register` on my server, **according** to if its from a **desktop** or **mobile**, so am thinking this redirect causes the issue, but if I share `philippidescompetition.com/users/register` which doesn't have a redirect, all meta data are still empty

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add an exception to your automatic redirect for the Facebook scraper (can be recognized by its User-Agent, see social plugins FAQ.)

Comment: @CBroe this makes sense for the redirect issue, what about the page that doesn't redirect? https://philippidescompetition.com/users/register

Comment: You’re only dreaming that this doesn’t redirect ... 302 Found with Location `https://philippidescompetition.com/users/spin/` first, and from there another 302 to `https://philippidescompetition.com/users/thankyou/`

Comment: @CBroe haha indeed you are right, added an if to check if its facebook scraper and works fine! thank you! Can you have this as an answer so we can close this question? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an exception to your automatic redirect for the Facebook scraper.

It can be recognized by its User-Agent, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1748179212062572